# ERROR: java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.SpringBusFactory

Tags: java, web-services, osgi, webclient, cxf

Helo!

I'm trying to create a Web Service client using CXF. My application is in OSGi. And I use the Felix Framework.

But the following error occurs:

```
[main] ERROR org.apache.cxf.BusFactory - Failed to determine BusFactory implementation class name.
java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.SpringBusFactory
    at java.lang.Class.asSubclass(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.cxf.BusFactory.getBusFactoryClass(BusFactory.java:280)
    at org.apache.cxf.BusFactory.newInstance(BusFactory.java:207)
    at org.apache.cxf.BusFactory.newInstance(BusFactory.java:194)
    at org.apache.cxf.BusFactory.getDefaultBus(BusFactory.java:90)
    at org.apache.cxf.BusFactory.getThreadDefaultBus(BusFactory.java:137)
    at org.apache.cxf.BusFactory.getThreadDefaultBus(BusFactory.java:122)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.spi.ProviderImpl.createServiceDelegate(ProviderImpl.java:89)
    at javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Service.java:36)
    at myorg.engine.test.mocks.soapservice.client.CHMService.<init>(CHMService.java:42)
    at myorg.engine.service.OSGiServiceTest.testSoapServiceMock(OSGiServiceTest.java:133)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.ops4j.pax.exam.raw.extender.intern.ProbeInvokerImpl.injectContextAndInvoke(ProbeInvokerImpl.java:112)
    at org.ops4j.pax.exam.raw.extender.intern.ProbeInvokerImpl.findAndInvoke(ProbeInvokerImpl.java:71)
    at org.ops4j.pax.exam.raw.extender.intern.ProbeInvokerImpl.call(ProbeInvokerImpl.java:58)
    at org.ops4j.pax.exam.nat.internal.NativeTestContainer.call(NativeTestContainer.java:83)
    at org.ops4j.pax.exam.spi.reactors.EagerSingleStagedReactor.invoke(EagerSingleStagedReactor.java:85)
    at org.ops4j.pax.exam.junit.JUnit4TestRunner$2.evaluate(JUnit4TestRunner.java:259)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:76)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.ops4j.pax.exam.junit.JUnit4TestRunner.run(JUnit4TestRunner.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)

[main] ERROR org.apache.cxf.BusFactory - Failed to instantiate bus factory.
java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.SpringBusFactory
    at java.lang.Class.asSubclass(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.cxf.BusFactory.newInstance(BusFactory.java:218)
    at org.apache.cxf.BusFactory.newInstance(BusFactory.java:194)
    at org.apache.cxf.BusFactory.getDefaultBus(BusFactory.java:90)
    at org.apache.cxf.BusFactory.getThreadDefaultBus(BusFactory.java:137)
    at org.apache.cxf.BusFactory.getThreadDefaultBus(BusFactory.java:122)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.spi.ProviderImpl.createServiceDelegate(ProviderImpl.java:89)
    at javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Service.java:36)
    at myorg.engine.test.mocks.soapservice.client.CHMService.<init>(CHMService.java:42)
    at myorg.engine.service.OSGiServiceTest.testSoapServiceMock(OSGiServiceTest.java:133)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.ops4j.pax.exam.raw.extender.intern.ProbeInvokerImpl.injectContextAndInvoke(ProbeInvokerImpl.java:112)
    at org.ops4j.pax.exam.raw.extender.intern.ProbeInvokerImpl.findAndInvoke(ProbeInvokerImpl.java:71)
    at org.ops4j.pax.exam.raw.extender.intern.ProbeInvokerImpl.call(ProbeInvokerImpl.java:58)
    at org.ops4j.pax.exam.nat.internal.NativeTestContainer.call(NativeTestContainer.java:83)
    at org.ops4j.pax.exam.spi.reactors.EagerSingleStagedReactor.invoke(EagerSingleStagedReactor.java:85)
    at org.ops4j.pax.exam.junit.JUnit4TestRunner$2.evaluate(JUnit4TestRunner.java:259)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:76)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.ops4j.pax.exam.junit.JUnit4TestRunner.run(JUnit4TestRunner.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
[org.ops4j.pax.exam.junit.JUnit4TestRunner] : Exception
org.ops4j.pax.exam.TestContainerException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.ops4j.pax.exam.raw.extender.intern.ProbeInvokerImpl.injectContextAndInvoke(ProbeInvokerImpl.java:118)
    at org.ops4j.pax.exam.raw.extender.intern.ProbeInvokerImpl.findAndInvoke(ProbeInvokerImpl.java:71)
    at org.ops4j.pax.exam.raw.extender.intern.ProbeInvokerImpl.call(ProbeInvokerImpl.java:58)
    at org.ops4j.pax.exam.nat.internal.NativeTestContainer.call(NativeTestContainer.java:83)
    at org.ops4j.pax.exam.spi.reactors.EagerSingleStagedReactor.invoke(EagerSingleStagedReactor.java:85)
    at org.ops4j.pax.exam.junit.JUnit4TestRunner$2.evaluate(JUnit4TestRunner.java:259)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:76)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.ops4j.pax.exam.junit.JUnit4TestRunner.run(JUnit4TestRunner.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)

Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.ops4j.pax.exam.raw.extender.intern.ProbeInvokerImpl.injectContextAndInvoke(ProbeInvokerImpl.java:112)
    ... 20 more

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.SpringBusFactory
    at org.apache.cxf.BusFactory.newInstance(BusFactory.java:224)
    at org.apache.cxf.BusFactory.newInstance(BusFactory.java:194)
    at org.apache.cxf.BusFactory.getDefaultBus(BusFactory.java:90)
    at org.apache.cxf.BusFactory.getThreadDefaultBus(BusFactory.java:137)
    at org.apache.cxf.BusFactory.getThreadDefaultBus(BusFactory.java:122)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.spi.ProviderImpl.createServiceDelegate(ProviderImpl.java:89)
    at javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Service.java:36)
    at myorg.engine.test.mocks.soapservice.client.CHMService.<init>(CHMService.java:42)
    at myorg.engine.service.OSGiServiceTest.testSoapServiceMock(OSGiServiceTest.java:133)
    ... 25 more

Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.SpringBusFactory
    at java.lang.Class.asSubclass(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.cxf.BusFactory.newInstance(BusFactory.java:218)
    ... 33 more
```

I said it could be because of different ClassLoader. Is it possible?

Any idea how to solve the problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it looks like you have two BusFactory class definitions. The SpringBusFactory implements one of them, and the asSubclass() call is made on the other. Since one BusFactory isn't the same class as the other, you'd get a CCE. Look for two different bundles containing the BusFactory class. One of them will be imported by the bundle that defines the SpringBusFactory.

Comment: There aren't two implementation of the class BusFactory in Felix. Only cxf-bundle. And my bundle not import the class SpringBusFactory, only javax.xml.ws.Service class.

Answer (score 0):

I think the "two BusFactory class definitions" is a red herring.

Not sure what version of CXF you're using (guessing 2.4.2) but that code is trying to do ServiceLoader kind of stuff using the thread context classloader when looking for subclass implementations.

My best guess is there some Spring "magic" that CXF relies on and your missing the bundle that provides it.  Looking at the CXF feature for Karaf it has loads of dependencies, check this and ensure you've got them all - at this point it may be easier to try this out using karaf with the CXF feature installed.

If you're using maven the features file can be accessed with this:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf.karaf</groupId>
        <artifactId>apache-cxf</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.2</version>
        <type>xml</type>
        <classifier>features</classifier>
    </dependency>
```

Some documentation on bus configuration [here](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/bus-configuration.html)

Comment: I found that SOAP clients does not work with CXF in OSGi environment.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen strange errors like that with pax-exam in the past.   Does this run outside of pax-exam in a "normal" OSGi environment?    Talend Service Factory ( http://talend.com/products/tsf ) has several examples (in the separate examples download package) of CXF clients and services running in OSGi and they all do work.